# Can I use LINQ to query two Lists to populate a single List

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following C# classes:

```
public class Definition
{
    public string partOfSpeech { get; set; } 
    public List<Def> Def { get; set; }
}

public class Def
{
    public string definition { get; set; }
    public List<string> synonyms { get; set; }
}

public class WebWordForm
{
    public string definition { get; set; }
    public string partOfSpeech { get; set; }
    public List<string> synonyms { get; set; }
    public List<string> typeOf { get; set; }
    public List<string> hasTypes { get; set; }
    public List<string> derivation { get; set; }
    public List<string> examples { get; set; }
}
```

What I have is the `a` which is a list of Definition

```
List<Definition> a
```

What I would like to do is to create:

```
List<WebWordForm> = a. << A LINQ statement if possible
```

Is it possible to do this with a LINQ statement?

Comment: What would be the values of `typeOf`, `hasTypes`, `derivation`, and `examples`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad - These would be left as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) to do something like this:

```
List<WebWordForm> results =
    a.SelectMany(definition => //each definition will generate many WebWordForms
        definition.Def
        .Select(def => new WebWordForm //each def will generate one WebWordForm
        {
            definition = def.definition,
            partOfSpeech = definition.partOfSpeech,
            synonyms = def.synonyms
        }))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `SelectMany` linq extension you could do this.

```
var result = a.SelectMany(x=> 
               {
                     x.Def.Select(s=> new WebWordForm()
                           {
                               partOfSpeech = x.partOfSpeech,
                               definition  = s.definition,
                               synonyms = s.synonyms,
                              // other properties
                           }).ToList()
                })
               .ToList() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
            List<Definition> a = new List<Definition>();
            List<WebWordForm> words = a.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Def.Select(y => new WebWordForm() {
                partOfSpeech = x.partOfSpeech,
                definition = y.definition,
                synonyms = y.synonyms
            }).ToList()
            ).FirstOrDefault();
```